# Laravel Slug Update Record

Tags: laravel, validation, slug

I want to ignore the slug if value is not changed. I am currently getting this error whenever i update the form.

[image]

This is my request on validation.

namespace App\Http\Requests\Admin;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class ProductInsertFormRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

```
/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'title'=>'required',
        'regularPrice'=>'required',
        'slug'=>'required|alpha_dash|min:5|max:255|unique:products,slug',
    ];
}
```

}

Comment: You are getting error on updating. Show the code of updating post.

Answer (score 1):

to ignore a particular row in database table when checking unique, you need to use `unique()` rule with `ignore()` function

```
'slug' => [
    'required',
    'alpha_dash',
    'min:5',
    'max:255',
    Rule::unique('products', 'slug')->ignore($this->product->slug)
]
```

This will check unique in 'slug' column of the 'products' table, except this particular row which has 'this slug'

Comment: import the rule `use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;`

Comment: sorry there is a mistake `ignore($this->product->slug)` I updated the answer

Comment: there should be an object you are giving to the `update()` function to update. I guess that objects name is 'product' so that objects is in the `$this` scope. you can access that object and that objects 'slug' as `$this->product->slug` (make sure to match this answer with your variable names)

Comment: This is my code in updating product.. public function update(ProductInsertFormRequest $request, $id)
    {
        $decrypted = Crypt::decrypt($id);
        $product=Product::whereId($decrypted)->firstOrFail();

        $product->title=$request->get('title');
        $product->slug=$request->get('slug'); $product->update();

Comment: ok. you are giving $id of a product to update. so you need to explicitly fetch the product or the products slug from database to check unique. to do so. in the `rules()` function do this. `$slug = Product::whereId(Crypt::decrypt($this->id))->pluck('slug')->first();` then in the ignore() function `ignore($slug)` give it a try

Answer (score 1):

1. Ignore() function in Rule is working only with id.
2. So I changed the code into following:

   ```
   public function rules()
   {
   $decrypted = Crypt::decrypt($this->id);
   //$slug = Product::whereId($decrypted)->pluck('slug')->first();

   //return dd($slug);
    return [
       'title'=>'required',
       'regularPrice'=>'required',
       'slug' => ['required', 'alpha_dash', 'min:5', 'max:255', Rule::unique('products', 'slug')->ignore($decrypted)]
   ];
    }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The best way you can do this is to use one form request to create and update a record

```
$postSlug = $this->route()->parameter('slug');
if (in_array($this->method(), ['PUT', 'POST']) && $postSlug) {
    $post = $this->postService->getBySlug($postSlug);
    $rules['slug'] = [
        'required',
        Rule::unique('posts')->ignore($post->id),
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, Please pay attention to "products" table name

```
/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'title'=>'required',
        'regularPrice'=>'required',
        'slug' => [
                'required',
                'alpha_dash',
                'min:5',
                'max:255',
                Rule::unique('products', 'slug')->ignore($this->product),
            ],
    ];
}
```